# what is the best way to solder wires onto 3d print beds

Tags: soldering

My 3d printer has a heated bed similar to the one in this picture.

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1.7gFKVXXXXbMapXXq6xXFXXXa/HICTOP-3MM-MK3-Aluminum-Heated-Bed-Hot-Bed-PCB-Heatbed-Platform-for-Reprap-3D-Printer-200W.jpg

It has some nice molex connectors but sadly the wires are too thin. With my multimeter I measured around 2v of drop caused by the wires they've used.

As soon as I soldered on supplmentary 10awg cable that droppped significantly but since the bed can get very hot depending on what filament am using, am worried the wires will eventually come loose  and cause a short.

Am assuming the manufacture has already thought of this. what kind of solder would they have likely used before I contaminated it?

Comment: Well, the point of a printer bed is to get hot – so, I'd argue, if the manufacturer sensibly designed the bed to be soldered to anything, then it won't get hot enough to cause any problems with usual solder. So: How hot does it actually get?

Comment: I still have kind of a problem with your assumption that the manufacturer has though of this – if that's the same people that chose wires that simply are too small, it's not shining a great light on their diligence when designing stuff.

Comment: according to the firmware the max is 255 celcius

Comment: That's a number, not a temperature. And: you can't trust anything here, there's definitely no calibration involved, you need to *measure*.

Comment: @Ageis That just means they only an unsigned 8 bit integer..

Comment: 60 °C is a typical temperature for a FDM 3D printer bed. I doubt any such bed will ever reach 100 °C under normal use, unless you're using some very exotic materials and techniques.

Comment: if it reaches any temperature where it starts melting solder, it will be the least of your worries because it will be melting your 3d prints too.

Comment: Alloys commonly used for electrical soldering are 60/40 Sn-Pb, which melts at 188 °C (370 °F), and 63/37 Sn-Pb used principally in electrical/electronic work. 63/37 is a eutectic alloy of these metals, which: has the lowest melting point (183 °C or 361 °F) of all the tin-lead alloys